# Short circuit protection using 555 IC 5 V, 3.3 V

Tags: 555, protection, short-circuit

I am trying to build a circuit for short circuit protection of 10 PCBs combined. These PCBs have 5 and 3.3 V.

I have tried building [this circuit](https://www.engineersgarage.com/short-circuit-detector/) and have changed the circuit a little bit keeping the principle the same and the circuit works fine. It powers up the circuit when there is no short circuit and turns off the circuit when there is a short circuit.

The input of the 555 comes from the 3.3 V point on the PCB, and the MOSFET drain goes to the 5 V input of the PCB. The source is connected to 5 V supply in.

[image]

It misbehaves when I combine 10 of these circuits, and also I have to use a single reset button for all circuits.

Comment: sorry I forget to mention the reset pin is also there pulled up 10k and the a push to ground push button the trigger takes the input again when reset is pressed.

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- You can [edit] your question, and you should, if you have new information. Do you see these textual links below your question? -- _How_ does "_it misbehave_"?

Comment: The PNP transistor should be NPN, and will require a base resistor to limit the base current.

Comment: @PeterBennett Actually only the C-B diode junction is being used here and the PNP could be replaced with an ordinary diode. The trigger voltage at pin 2 of the 555 is 1.66V and the C-B diode means the voltage at pin 2 of the 555 will be below that when the "3.3 PCB1" voltage is less than 1.66-0.65 = 1V or so.

Comment: Better Falstad simulation: https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgBzEFPPEbNN179shKFDYAnIXzDEUM7ihriaGOGwBKisBjE9ZNFVSo0qSE1GgItSlQfDzFls+FgXxMGwHc7i5VQOkGy+DgKBwrjGIf6uDijKEqHCcgoOumLByXwB-hgKwWjkUdyu2KKlpiAAagAOAJYAdiic-JD2+W32wiYxJbnxrsG1XZWjmAoQvQAuY-HC6SAsS14krDR4kIQ8YJAoYGJg7shUACYMAGYAhgCuADbTbEV+8YnhtDV3APZXpwA6tTYAA9wChiPx1PwEHxsDgPmAVABVADODD+yOqXweVw4aORyLu9XOknR0y+6IAxgALK6NXHo6rfX4AthfEDgwjGWiQUjUGDwHl6BDbDwKcHYNjYGEgABiU3ESGWmOxuLYQA

Comment: @ErikR falsetad is really for beginners.

Comment: THIS CIRCUIT WORKS FINE SINGLE CIRCUIT IS OK TESTED IT WORKS i NEED HELP IN ONLY COMBINING THE 10 CIRCUITS YOU CAN GO ON LINK PROVIDED TO UNDERSTAND THE THEORY

Comment: Welcome!  You'll get better mileage from this site if to try to help those who are trying to help you.  The first thing that comes to mind is: what is the power supply?  Are you certain it can handle ten of these?  What current measurements do you get?  When you say "misbehave", what actually happens?

Comment: @jonathanjo The 555 is only used for the comparator and the flip-flip. The comparator can change the FF to turn the output on but it can't reset the FF -- and that's exactly what's needed for this application because you want the supply cut off until a manual reset is performed.

Comment: @zuhaib How does the circuit "misbehave"? And when you say you "have to use a single reset button for all circuits" do you mean you _want_ to use a single reset button but it's not working for you?

Comment: @ErikR ... well spotted, I missed that!

Comment: Yes exactly erik this is problem.  I have combined 2 of these circuits with single reset button and then with 10 then it misbehaves it detects short circuit in some circuit and short the input in some circuit.  You understant my problem exactly rest people are all commenting on transistor .

Answer (score 1):

A PNP emitter follower is a good solution for a 3.3 V CPU, because one less resistor is needed. At 5 V supply voltage, C-E can be reversed. This mode of operation is called the ***reverse-active region***.  (Major advantage of operating the transistor with its emitter and collector roles reversed, is that the saturation voltage drop is lower than obtained in the normal mode. This is why such devices were used long time ago as analog switches in low voltage control electronics in discrete applications. In reverse mode, the current gain is lower too.)
So here both versions work fine with a PNP transistor. Now the transistor works in linear mode.
[image]
[image]
Each NE555 must have a decoupling capacitor of at least 1 µF. Do not connect the RESET pins directly, only via an NPN transistor to the push button. Any type of NPN transistor will do. I don't see any other problems right now.
[image]